# Can not create bucket "The account for the specified project has been disabled."

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have an old GAE application (in production since 2011) that use Cloud Storage service since it is available in beta. I have not touched this apps for almost 1 year now.

I have to do some administrative task and want to create new buckets in Cloud Storage.

I have activated 
- the application in Google Cloud Console
- the billing for this application in Google Cloud Console

I see the Google Cloud Storage tab, when I click on it it is empty, and when I try to create a new bucket I see the error message:

> The account for the specified project has been disabled.

How can I fix that?

Why I do not see my existing bucket? (created long time ago using the old Web interface)

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: 
Go to http://code.google.com/apis/console
Select your project.
Visit the services tab.
Make sure cloud storage is on. 

I believe this message can be presented if Cloud Storage is off for a given project.

Comment: Great, with that confirmation I'll go ahead and repost this as an answer.

Comment: I'm still having the issue, after enabling GCS in the APIs and Auth tab. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by going to the new console; but I have not done anything special. Now that it is working... and do not remember all the steps. Sorry

Answer (score 20):

This can happen when the Cloud Storage service isn't turned on for your project.  Do the following:

1. Visit http://cloud.google.com/console
2. Select your project
3. Visit the APIs & Auth tab
4. Find Google Cloud Storage in the list of services
5. Turn on Google Cloud Storage

Comment: what if we are getting this issue even when API is enabled. I am getting this issue when job running on dataproc cluster is trying to access a gcs bucket.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue .While every API was enabled after deep diving i realized there is some problem relating to my billing.

Comment: Firebase gives us free to use but what kind of problem with relation to billing information.