# The account for bucket "XXX" has been disabled

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

Running the following code **on my local machine** to create a new bucket on **google storage** , I got an error "**StorageException: The account for bucket "my-new-bucket-abc" has been disabled**".

```
String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_PATH = "C:\\gcpconfig\\My First Project-6f9cff47c4f0.json";

Storage storage =
    StorageOptions.newBuilder()
        .setCredentials(
            ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
                new FileInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_PATH)))
        .build()
        .getService();

String bucketName = "my-new-bucket-abc";

// Creates the new bucket
Bucket bucket = storage.create(BucketInfo.of(bucketName));

System.out.printf("Bucket %s created.%n", bucket.getName());
```

However, I **could download** the files from google storage by running the following code:

```
String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_PATH = "C:\\gcpconfig\\My First Project-6f9cff47c4f0.json";

Storage storage =
    StorageOptions.newBuilder()
        .setCredentials(
            ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
                new FileInputStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_PATH)))
        .build()
        .getService();

BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("nmjcloud_jar_test","addons/simple-bean-1.0.jar");
Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);

Path path = Paths.get("D:\\lib\\simple-bean-1.0.jar");
blob.downloadTo(path);

System.out.printf("Download successfully%n");
```

The complete error message is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: The account for bucket "my-new-bucket-abc" has been disabled.
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:221)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$2.call(StorageImpl.java:112)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$2.call(StorageImpl.java:109)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:108)
    at com.example.storage.QuickstartSample.main(QuickstartSample.java:58)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "The account for bucket \"my-new-bucket-abc\" has been disabled.",
    "reason" : "accountDisabled"
  } ],
  "message" : "The account for bucket \"my-new-bucket-abc\" has been disabled."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:219)
    ... 7 more
```

**Does it mean that the account I used doesn't have permission to create buckets?**

<s>When running on GCP VM with service account key, I got the following error:</s>

```
Caused by: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Insufficient Permission
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate (HttpStorageRpc.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create (HttpStorageRpc.java:221)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$2.call (StorageImpl.java:112)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$2.call (StorageImpl.java:109)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit (DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run (RetryHelper.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries (RetryHelper.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create (StorageImpl.java:108)
    at com.example.storage.QuickstartSample.createBucket (QuickstartSample.java:33)
    at com.example.storage.QuickstartSample.main (QuickstartSample.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from (GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError (AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError (AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute (HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute (AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create (HttpStorageRpc.java:219)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$2.call (StorageImpl.java:112)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$2.call (StorageImpl.java:109)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit (DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run (RetryHelper.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries (RetryHelper.java:51)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create (StorageImpl.java:108)
    at com.example.storage.QuickstartSample.createBucket (QuickstartSample.java:33)
    at com.example.storage.QuickstartSample.main (QuickstartSample.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

I tried again on GCP VM, and it works now.

**Some Settings about my Google Cloud Platform:**

**1. Billing account**:
[image]

**2. The service account key:**

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "ornate-shine-192301",
  "private_key_id": "6f9cff47c4f0f8b1263bbf515f7e3318dcc88487",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\n3DsGix3gso9/jJjt4p5G5II=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "gcsserviceaccountname1@ornate-shine-192301.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "114270155500502944764",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/gcsserviceaccountname1%40ornate-shine-192301.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

**3. Permissions for project "My First Project" :**
[image]

**4. Google Cloud Storage API Library :**
[image]

**Supplement:**
1. I'm able to create buckets either using `gsutil` command line or `GCP console`.
2. Java API **could download** files from GCS.
3. On **GCP VM**, I **could** create buckets using Java API with **application default credentials**.(update20180316)

> You are running on a Google Compute Engine virtual machine. The service credentials associated with this virtual machine will automatically be used by Application Default Credentials, so it is not necessary to use this command(`gcloud auth application-default login`).

**Reference Links:**
1. [APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)
2. [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-resources-java)
3. [Creating Storage Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets#storage-create-bucket-java)

Comment: Is billing enabled for the project that owns the bucket "my-new-bucket-abc"?

Comment: no, I'm just using the free trial. I could create buckes by GCP console.

Comment: Free trial couldn't create buckets by Java API?

Comment: You can create buckets under the free trial, but a billing account must be associated with the project (free tier billing accounts are fine). It's possible that billing has been disabled on your project for some reason: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_a_new_project

Comment: There is already a billing account associated with this project.

Comment: What else can I do to check possible reasons or find out a solution?

Comment: are you able to create buckets either using gsutil command line or through the GUI? just to make sure this is specific to the Java API. Can you also try using another account?

Comment: What does GUI refer to? Do you mean google cloud platform console? I could create buckets using it. So I think this is specific to the Java API. And do you mean trying to create another service account key? I have done that. But the result is the same.

Comment: You may be experiencing the same issue as [this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672860/can-not-create-bucket-the-account-for-the-specified-project-has-been-disabled)

Comment: The difference is that I can create bucket using Google Cloud Platform console.

Comment: @niaomingjian would you like a bounty?

Comment: @burrito77 What do you mean? Could you explain more?

Comment: @niaomingjian right underneath this comment you should see an option to start a bounty. Having a bounty will pretty much guarantee an answer to your question.

Comment: @burrito77 A good idea. Thanks

Comment: I have checked what I know that have an impact on GCS access. And I have updated this question.

Comment: I'm not sure publishing your service account key to a public website is necessarily the best idea

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yeah, you're right. I just want to provide sufficient information to help check the issue.

Comment: @niaomingjian if the API is disabled you can still create through the Console but not through API calls. Please make sure your API is enabled in APIs & Services

Comment: @PatrickW Does "4. Google Cloud Storage API Library" in the question mean my API is enabled?

Comment: you have to go to API & Services > Dashboard. Look for the " Google Cloud Storage" API. If it is not listed in the Dashboard, it means the API is disabled and you will need to enable it. You can enable it in "API & Services > Library" and search for Storage. Note there are 2 Storage APIs (one for Cloud Storage and one for Storage JSON API).

Comment: @PatrickW They have been enabled. And on GCP VM, I could create buckets by Java API. I just couldn't do that from my local machine.

Comment: Whatever the reason for your project is not working you shouldn't **EVER NEVER EVER** share in a public site your account's authentication information specially the private key. Now anyone that sees it can use it to use whatever is available in that account.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Got it. I have deleted that credential from GCP.

Comment: Maybe you had the wrong political opinion and your account was banned?

Comment: @Chloe I could upload and download files from it. I just couldn't create the bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps local environment mistakes, like environment variable names, string quotation marks and so on.

Comment: Two years ago, I set `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` environment variable to another project. And I forgot to delete it. I debugged to find out that project ID is incorrect.